# How to parse url params with multidimensional params?

Tags: python-3.x

I use python 3 and need transform the request uri params to dictionary.

My example URL is: `http://example.com/?item[test1]=foo&abc[0][6]=foo`

In php from `$_GET` gets a dictionary with multidimensional array like as:

```
Array(
    item => Array(
        test1 => foo
    ),
    abc => Array(
        0 => Array(
              6 => foo
        )
    )
)
```

But using urlparse can not get the data as dictionary:

```
>>> import urllib.parse as urlparse
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse('http://example.com/?item[test1]=foo&abc[0][6]=foo').query)
{'item[test1]': ['foo'], 'abc[0][6]': ['foo']}
```

Get the `item[test1]` as single parameter.

How to get the multidimensional dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can check here: https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser,
The parser.py (https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser/blob/master/querystring_parser/parser.py) should answer your requirements

Comment: Ohh thanks :D, but need django package: `from django.core.management import setup_environ`, for now, I do not want to install django just to process the parameters.