# FastAPI Parse HTTP GET list

Tags: python, fastapi

I have problem with parsing URL in FastAPI. It's HTTP GET method that has format I have never
encountered.

I have URL like this

```
.../api/?products[0][id]=ABC123&products[0][count]=1&products[1][id]=ABC124&products[1][count]=2
```

and I need to parse it in FastAPI, I wasnt able to figure it out using

```
def method_name(products):
    print(products)
```

or

```
def method_name(products: List[int] = Query(none):
    print(products)
```

in any way I get None

what I did so far is

```
def a(request: Request):
    print(parse.parse_qs(str(request.query_params))) 
    print(request.query_params)
```

I get

```
{'products[0][id]': ['ABC123'], 'products[0][count]': ['1'], 'products[1][id]': ['ABC124'], 'products[1][count]': ['2']}
```

but thats as useful as `None`

I need a way to get this into format like

```
[{'id': 'ABC123', 'count': '1'}, ...]
```

or basically any other readable format

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I was able to solve this by writing this snippet

```
parse_dict = parse.parse_qs(str(request.query_params))
_values = list(parse_dict.values())
usable = []
for i in range(0, len(parse_dict), 2):
    usable.append(
        {
            "id": _values[i],
            "count": _values[i+1]
        }
    )
```

but that's hardly good solution so I would still be happy if someone could help me with this riddle

Comment: To be honest, I've never seen your way of encoding things. Passing such complex objects is usually done via POST requests

Comment: I don't think fastapi supports parsing this kind of nested url encoding out of the box. Maybe the library mentioned here helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56463743/5768147.  This related questions also seems interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261513/is-there-a-spec-for-nested-urlencoded-params.

Comment: @lsadi it´s not my way, its from system I have to integrate with

Comment: @mihi thanks I will have a look at it